# Is there a way to interface the WSO2 BPM task engine and manage human tasks outside the WSO2 management console

Tags: wso2

Currently, if user needs to respond to a new human task, he needs to log in tho the WSO2 admin web console,
In the web console there are other things besides the tasks display.
Since I will have users which shouldn't be involved with the BPM server itself, but they will need to act on tasks, is there a way to make a standalone application which would communicate to the tasks engine in order to retrieve tasks and manage them?
So, is there a way to manage human tasks externally?

Comment: yes, we have usecases too, it's just a matter of webservice call to API functions. http://thiliniishaka.blogspot.com/2012/12/approval-based-user-registration.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a SOAP [API](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/service-stubs/org.wso2.carbon.humantask.skeleton/4.0.2/src/main/resources/ws-humantask-api.wsdl),You can remotely use this API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will have a look!